# Calling a static method from a class throws the type initializer for DS.API threw an exception

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a utility class which contains several static methods that are used in my projects classes.
The utility class itself which I call it `API` is static.
Now When ever i try to use a method, I get the :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in DS.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for 'DS.API' threw an exception.
```

[image: exception which occurs when i try to execute a static method]

I also noticed in inner exception I get the

> "object reference not set to an abject reference exception.  I have no
>   idea why I get that!

But this makes no sense , since i am calling a method which returns

```
DateTime.Now.ToBinary();
```

which is actually implemented like this :

```
public static long GenerateID()
{
    return GetTimeStamp();
}


[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static long GetTimeStamp()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToBinary();
}
```

Something to note though, this utility class is partial. might this be the cause? 
All static variables are initialized so i cant see where this error comes from!

the structure of classes are like this :

```
namespace Test
{
    public abstract class BASE
    {
        //fields 
        int x;
        protected long id;

        //different constructors
        public BASE(BaseInfo info)
        {
            this.id = BASE.GenerateID();
            this.x = info.x;
        }

        //methods which need specific implementations
        public abstract string Createmsg();

        //general public methods that all childern should have
        public void DoXYZ()
        {
            int x = 0;
        }

        //helper methods
        public static long GenerateID()
        {
            DS.API.GENERATEID();
        }
    }



    public class Child1 : BASE
    {
        int childvar;
        public Child1(ChildInfo info):Base(ChilInfo)
        {
            childvar = info.childvar;
        }
        public override string Createmsg()
        {
            return "my id is "+id.ToString();
        }
    }
}

namespace DS
{
    public static class API
    {
        public static long GenerateID()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToBinary();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the stack trace log :

```
   at DS.API.GenerateID()
   at DLSR.GenerateID() in C:\SDNC\Development\Libraries\DS\DS\Models\DLSR.cs:line 690
   at DLSR..ctor(DLSRInfo info) in C:\SDNC\Development\Libraries\DS\DS\Models\DLSR.cs:line 275
   at VERDLSR..ctor(VERDLSRInfo info) in C:\SDNC\Development\Libraries\DS\DS\Models\VERDLSR.cs:line 99
   at SDNCTestBed.VER.btnCreat_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SDNC_System\Development\Applications\SDNCTestBed\SDNCTestBed\VER.cs:line 65
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at SDNCTestBed.Program.Main() in c:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SDNC_System\Development\Applications\SDNCTestBed\SDNCTestBed\Program.cs:line 19
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What is the inner exception? Try to solve that one. Show us the exception and the code of the `API` class (specifically the static variables initialized and the constructors).

Comment: I get the object is not initialized expection. while i shouldnt! since i have no idea what it is talking about! it just needs to call a static method which calls DateTime.Now.ToBinary() method !!

Comment: whats the down vote for? seriously?

Comment: I doubt that is all code for the `API` class. (Btw, I didn't downvote, so I don't know why)

Comment: there is nothing else left, by the way, API is partial and there are 4 classes that make the whole class ( i separated the logically different chores into sub files, and for ease of access, made them a partial API class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of API related codes, i found this line of code :

```
public static string DefaultImagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/DefaultImg/unknown-person.jpg");
```

Which was added by my colleague. 
And that object reference is not set to ... exception is because of this!
Removing this solved everything.
So when ever this happens to you, if you are using a static class, make sure you review all of the fields and properties of your static class, not to miss what i had missed earlier!

Comment: That was the entire purpose of asking you to post the full code of the API class...

Comment: hundreds of codes can not be easily copied and pasted here for a question!, apart from that , from the security point of view that was not possible

Comment: That's why I asked for `specifically the static variables initialized and the constructors`.

Comment: yes, thats exactly where i missed , the exact place i  never forget!(actually my colleage didnt define the variable in fields section, it was in the middle of file among the methods!, thats why i missed it,and looking at the fields section of class, fields were fine!)  Thank you alot by the way